# WebView2 Stopped working after installing some NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio

[[Question on GitHub]](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/issues/2710)

WebView2 Stopped working after installing some NuGet packages.
I don't know which package triggered it, but I have the following installed:
-Costura.Fody
-Newtonsoft.Json
(-WebView2)
I have also updated all of them.

The error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XDG0003 The file or assembly "Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf, Version=1.0.1823.32, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a8ab48044d2601e" or one of its dependencies was not found. The system cannot find the specified file. Program D:\VS2022\Program\MainWindow.xaml 11

Everything is present and up to date. Therefore, I request assistance.